# SQL - Return latest (id) result if resultset contains more than one row

Tags: sql, db2

I need to a condition on my select where I would get the latest (id) row if the query will return more than one result. (IBM db2)

I.e:

```
ID--NUM1--COUNTRY--NUM2

1--123--SE--123

2--123--US--123
```

Instead of having the two rows returned I would like to have row 2 returned.

**EDIT:**

My query looks like this now:

```
SELECT   LET1.INSTANCE_ID, COU.CODE, SUP1.SUPPLIERID, PAR.PARTNUMBER 

FROM     TABLES

WHERE    TABLEJOIN_CONDITIONS

AND      TABLE.COLUMN IN ('11994', '12345' and so on)
```

But this query can return duplicate rows.

Like:

```
ID--NUM1--COUNTRY--NUM2

1--123--SE--11994 (11994 appearing twice, then I want the latest row which is row number 2)

2--123--US--11994
```

Comment: So you want the row with the greatest ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Sort on the id in descendng order, and get only the first record.

I'm not up to date on db2 syntax, but something like:

```
SELECT id, num1, country, num2
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY ID DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: This of course assumes he's directly querying per `num1`/`country`/`num2`, or it's only going to give him one row _total_, as opposed to one row per tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on which numbers make it "unique", but if you just wanted the latest `ID` for each `NUM1, NUM2` combination, then you could do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT A.*, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NUM1, NUM2 ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RN
    FROM YOUR_TABLE A
)
WHERE RN = 1
```

The sub-select will assign a row number for each `num1`, `num2` combination, order it by the `ID`, and only pick the first row for that combination.